# Stanford CoreNLP in R: Spanish language not working

Tags: r, stanford-nlp

I'm starting to use Stanford CoreNLP package in R in order to do some text analysis in Spanish. So, I try the following:

```
R

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages("coreNLP")
Installing package into ‘/home/ach/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.rediris.es/src/contrib/coreNLP_0.4-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 17392 bytes (16 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 16 KB

* installing *source* package ‘coreNLP’ ...
** package ‘coreNLP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (coreNLP)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpO3q77z/downloaded_packages’
> library(coreNLP)
> downloadCoreNLP(type="base")
trying URL 'http://nlp.stanford.edu/software//stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 360824440 bytes (344.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 344.1 MB

[1] 0
> 
> downloadCoreNLP(type="spanish")
trying URL 'http://nlp.stanford.edu/software//stanford-spanish-corenlp-2015-01-08-models.jar'
Content type 'application/x-java-archive' length 25007256 bytes (23.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 23.8 MB

> initCoreNLP()
Searching for resource: config.properties
Adding annotator tokenize
TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.7 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [3.5 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.2 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.3 sec].
Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath: edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.4 sec].
Adding annotator dcoref
Adding annotator sentiment
> > sInes <- "Hola padre. Acabo de llegar a casa. Tengo ganas de cenar"
> annotation <- annotateString(sInes)
> token <- getToken(annotation)
> token[token$sentence==2,c(1:4,7)]
  sentence id  token  lemma POS
4        2  1  Acabo  Acabo NNP
5        2  2     de     de NNP
6        2  3 llegar llegar NNP
7        2  4      a      a  DT
8        2  5   casa   casa  FW
9        2  6      .      .   .
```

Everything seem to work fine (no errors can be seen, as far as I can see), but it does not work. For example, "casa" is tagged as Foreign Word (FW) which is not correct.

So, does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks a lot

Agustin

Answer (score 3):

You need to not only download Spanish, but set the tokenizer to Spanish as well:

```
props.setProperty("tokenize.language", "es");
```

Comment: I've tried this in the R shell, both before and after the initCoreNLP() command, but I get: Error: could not find function "props.setProperty"

Answer (score 3):

The author of the package recently made updates that make it a breeze to change language settings.

```
# update to newest version of the package
devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")

# download base library (mandatory):
coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP()

# download desired language library:
coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP(type="spanish")

# attach package
library(coreNLP)

# run initCoreNLP specifying your language of choice
initCoreNLP(type="spanish")
```